# LSDV-Estimator and Within estimator

Tags: self-study, categorical-data, repeated-measures, least-squares

For an assignment we need to run a "least squares dummy variable" regression on a panel data set. We were given that the data contains heteroscedasticity and autocorrelation. Thus, I employed **Newey-West standard errors**.

My regression is now:

$$Y_{it}=\alpha+\beta_1 X_{it}+...+ p_1D_t+v_{it}$$

I have an dependent variable Y, some independent variables X and I control for year fixed effects.

I read that the using LSDV using OLS equals the Within Estimator. Does that mean I only observe within observation over my panel identifiers?